# Can't bind to 'data-link' since it isn't a known property of 'td'

Tags: angularjs, angular, html-table, navigation, angular-upgrade

Actually I was doing angular migration from angularjs to angular 10. While doing the upgrade we are facing an issue with this `data-link` binding. keep getting the error

> Can't bind to 'data-link' since it isn't a known property of 'td'

Actually they were building a grid(table structure) in the UI, It's row click will navigate to some other page, the whole row will act as a hyperlink and they were passing the clicked cell information to the next page.

Following is the angularjs code which we needs to convert to angular 10.

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in vm.responseData" ng-click="vm.goToSummary(data,this)">
    <td data-link="{{data.Description}}">
        <span ng-bind="data.Description" 
              data-link="{{data.Description}}">
        </span>
    </td>
    <td data-link="{{data.Description + 'propA'}}">
        <div data-link="{{data.Description + 'propA'}}" >{{data.propA}}</div>
        <span data-link="{{data.Description + 'propA_' + 'Priority'}}">{{data.propACount}}</span>
    </td>
    <td data-link="{{data.Description + 'propB'}}">
        <div data-link="{{data.Description + 'propB'}}" >{{data.propB}}</div>
        <span data-link="{{data.Description + 'propB_' + 'Priority'}}">{{data.propBCount}}</span>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Can someone help me to identify how to use data-link binding in angular, or how to resolve this error. will also be helpful if someone can  tell what's the role of `data-link` link in the above code.

Comment: I coudn't remember nothing like "data-link", so I imagine is a [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) of html, that can be used by jQuery or similar. In Angular you can add an attribute using `[attr.name_of_attribute]="expresion"`, if this case `[attr.data-link]="data.Description+'propA'"`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was migrating a code from jQuery so the original:

```
data-sentence="mydata"
```

changes to:

```
data-sentence="{{oracion.oracion}}"
```

As it works, for specific `data` attribute you should bracket the attribute and add `attr.`

But the following does't work:

```
[attr.data-sentence]="{{oracion.oracion}}"
```

So you need to convert it to:

```
[attr.data-sentence]="oracion.oracion"
```

But in consideration I think is better rethink the functional system of this in consideration the attribute could not be useful since you can keep the data in the angular controller (component)